# Define filters order

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to code some filters for a text processor. I receive from a socket files that I have to process line by line. For each line I need to apply some filters and in an specific order. For example, for one file I'll use filter 1, filter 2, filter 3 and after that filter 2 again.

My question is what is the best way to run this filters in an specific order and how to define them so I can add more filters without have to change a lot of code? What is the best way to ensure a high speed executing this filters line by line?

Answer (score 1):

I would use probably chain of responsibility.
I assume a filter says either `true` (include/accept the line),
or `false` (do not include i.e. reject this line).

So chain several filters in a chain, if filter 1 returns `true`,
then pass the line to the next filter 2 (and so on). Otherwise
(if any filter from the chain says `false`), reject the line and
don't go checking with the next filter from the chain.

[chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

*What is the best way to ensure a high speed

executing this filters line by line?*

This depends on too many factors so
it is hard to give a response on it.

Comment: Chain of responsibility was my first idea but as long as all filters must be executed I don't know if this is the best approach. My question was not clear enough. Filters doesn't accept or reject lines. Maybe the appropriate word would be Normalizers because they work over the line replacing words, symbols, correcting grammar, etc. The speed of this chain must be high because I'll have to process thousands of lines in real time so I don't want to lose time in a slow iteration loop. This doesn't to be the case using your suggested pattern.

Comment: Well, if the main concern is speed I would rather look at some good algorithms (based on the operations I want to perform on the lines), rather than at design patterns. Only once I decide on the algorithm, I would look for a particular design pattern.

Comment: You should provide more details what these line operations are or post a new question, if you want to get a better response on this part.

Comment: I've written another question. I think it is better explained now. I would be grateful if you could take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501354/design-pattern-to-apply-over-text-normalizers-chain?noredirect=1#comment32466388_21501354

Answer (score 1):

This is quite similar to Servlet Filters, except that you want to be able to apply the same filter multiple times.

As others have suggested Chain of Responsibility might be appropriate, especially if a filter needs to have the ability to abort further execution of other filters and needs an "around" control, i.e. it wants to do some processing before the rest of the chain does it thing and do some other processing after.

**But to me what seems more important is to separate out the notions of individual filter and a chain which is the arrangement of the filters in a chain (or sequence).**

I am thinking of unix pipes. Each `Filter` does its own thing, without knowing where its input comes from and who consumes its output.

A `Controller` component creates the chains as necessary, I don't know whether a single chain applies to all files, or there are is fixed set of chains one of which is chosen in some way for each file, or a new chain is created for each file.

`FilterChain` applies the filters. If you are following Chain of Responsibility pattern then it only has to invoke the first (top) filter otherwise it has to iterate through all filters in the chain.