# Design pattern to apply over text normalizers chain

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a program that receives periodically files containing multiple lines that I process line by line. To process these lines I developed some text normalizers that work over the line to transform it. For example, one normalization could be remove stopwords, grammar correction, remove urls, etc.

The normalizers used for a given file must be decided dynamically so I can change the amount of them and alter its order also. For some files I only have to remove, for example, stopwords, but others require more normalizers and in some cases I must apply one twice.

My first idea to organize the code was apply Chain of Responsibility pattern. In this case I would have something like this:

[image]

As you can see in the diagram, three normalizers are used in order, and after that the first normalizer is used again. This is only an example. In other escenario I could have 7 normalizers without repetitions and in other the second normalizer would be executed before the third. So, the main idea is to have multiple normalizers and define a chain dinamically in which I could have repetitions.

My problem with this approach is that all the members of the chain are executed always (no reject condition) and I have thousand and thousand of lines to process so I don't want to spend a lot of time iterating over the chain.

So, my question is, what is the best way to implement what I need giving me the chance to add new normalizers without have to rewrite code and keeping a high speed in chain iteration?

If you need more information just ask for it and I'll edit the question.

Comment: On what condition do you decide which normalizer is needed?

Comment: Received files contains that info.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need a design pattern for this. If each line needs to be processed by the given normalizers it's pretty straight forward. You could just have a list of normalizers and iterate over then line by line.

Answer (score 1):

*"My problem with this approach is that all the members of the chain are executed always (no reject condition) and I have thousand and thousand of lines to process so I don't want to spend a lot of time iterating over the chain."*

David,

This is kind of contradictory. You say you want to execute all normalizers,
e.g. 1,2,3,1 in this order on each line from the file. But then you say your
problem is that you execute all of them which could slow you down. Is this
sequence of normalizers dependent on the current line you are processing?
If it's not dependent, and you need to run 1,2,3,1 on all lines, then you
just need to do it. I don't see really how you can avoid calling some
normalizers but still call all of them on each line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to avoid some calls. I'm just looking for a fast implementation to not lose too many time iterating over the chain.

Comment: David, fast implementation has more to do with algorithms than with design patterns. I think I mentioned it on your previous question too.

Comment: Yes, of course, and that is aldo part of my question. I could use lists, an approach similar to the one used in chain of responsibility pattern implementations, etc. I'm asking you your opinion about what could be the fastest one.

Comment: @MorenoGarcia do you have performance issues or are you trying to optimize to early? I would say just implement it in the simplest way and if some performance bottleneck appears, investigate that and make improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether the following fits your architectural ideas.

Start with a *declarative* **control model in XML**:

- The normalizers.

  - control messages that every normalizer can give
- The default sequence(s) of normalizers.
- What you do per control message - "add normalizer 3 afterwards, remove prior normalizer 1"

*This allows to reason about combined effects of changes. Separating control messages (no more tags) from actual actions (remove tag normalizer) might be suitable.*

One could read the XML with **JAXB** using POJOs and annotations. *Very easy.*

The **control glue** may **log all**, so one may ascertain no suboptimal things happen.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look  to [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)'s Analyzers design, which is basically an Abstract Factory of composite objects (the `Analyzer`), and accomplish a similar task to the one you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing all normalizers for each line, the design pattern is a list of Commands, as there is no checking of responsibility for each normalizer.

As I understand the list of normalizers is constant per file, so creating it is not an issue. Also you said that you iterate all of them for each line, so the only thing you can tweak performance is the iteration itself.

I would use a design like this:
1) all normalizers implement a common interface

```
interface Normalizer {
  String normalize(String line);
}
```

You most likely have something like that in place already.

2) When opening the file (or starting to process it) you determine which normalizers you need. Unless your files are short and you have many of them, it is not important how you do that. You could have a factory that returns the proper list of normalizers for some criteria. It could use a textual list of class names or create the list of commands hard-coded. Also consider Joop Eggen's answer here.

```
class Factory {
  List<Normalizer> buildNormalizers(DeterminingCriteria criteria) { ... } 
}
```

If you have the need to change the list without redeploying, then a text file with a list of class names is handy. If you also need to add a new normalizer at this time you need to change code anyway, so a class that builds the list of normalizers would be fine as well.

As the normalizers need to be stateless here, you can reuse double normalizers in the list. In fact you can reuse all normalizers for all files unless your application is started for each file again and again. As your commands are state-less they are also working concurrently on different files, if needed. Maybe use a design like that:

```
  class Factory {
    private Map<Criteria, Normalizer> cachedNormalizers;
    public Factory() {
      // create all normalizers from a master map 
      // or hard coded here and add to map.
    }
    List<Normalizer> buildNormalizers(DeterminingCriteria criteria) { 
      // create an empty list and get normalizers from 
      // cached map depending on criterias you need.   
    } 
  }
```

3) Then in the main code you just iterate these for each line. Iteration the list should be pretty fast, like that (pseudocode):

```
List<Normalizer> normalizers = factory.buildNormalizers(currentFileCriteria);
for (String line in lines) {
  String currentLine = line;
  for (Normalizer n in normalizers) {
    currentLine = n.normalize(currentLine);
  }
  doSomethingWithFinished(currentLine);
}
```